# How to add Full READ permissions and remove Full Control Permission on web application using powershell

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, permissions

How do I give a user "full read" permissions to a web application with PowerShell?

The Script below assigns "full control" to a user on this web application with "full control" and "full read".

```
$w = Get-SPWebApplication -identity http://webapplication
$w.GrantAccessToProcessIdentity("Domain\SPUsername")
```

How do I remove "full control" and "full read" permissions using PowerShell to an user on a web application?

Comment: Hi, did my answere help you? If yes. pls mark it as the correct one. If not. Ask some more questions.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this could be your solution:

[Add a User or Group to the SPWebApplication User Policy for all Web Applications in the farm](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/josrod/archive/2012/01/10/add-a-user-or-group-to-the-spwebapplication-user-policy-for-all-web-applications-in-the-farm.aspx)

The interesting code should be

```
Get-SPWebApplication http://sharepoint2010 | foreach { 
$webApp = $_ 
$policy = $webApp.Policies.Add($userOrGroup, $displayName) 
$policyRole = $webApp.PolicyRoles.GetSpecialRole([Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPolicyRoleType]::FullRead) 
$policy.PolicyRoleBindings.Add($policyRole) 
$webApp.Update()
```

}

The critical part is the

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPolicyRoleType]
```

Enumeration.

[SPPolicyRoleType enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.sppolicyroletype.aspx)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi how i use this code, is this powershell code? How to remove full control and full read permissions using powerhsell?

Comment: just remove (in the same script before adding) the user itself from the PolicyRoles and readd him with full read permission to that webapplication. You don't need to change that.
And yes this is PowerShell!

Comment: hi if you can , please post script for  how to remove full permissions and full read permissions ??

Comment: what is the difference between GrantAccessToProcessIdentity(“Domain/User”)? and above powershell code?

Comment: this script for all web applications or only one web application ?

Comment: $policy = $webApp.Policies.Remove($userOrGroup, $displayName)  i am getting error